# Java 2 array min max avg?

Tags: java

How do I create a loop to generate min, max, avg for 2 array lists, i have only generated the min, max and avg with sum for single array lists so far.

These are the 2 arrays User[] & Withdrawals[]:

```
User, Withdrawals
1 , 90.00
2 , 85.00
4 , 75.00
5 , 65.00
2 , 40.00
1 , 80.00
3 , 50.00
5 , 85.00
4 , 80.00
1 , 70.00

size = 10
```

This is what i have tried, as i have no clue about 2 arrays interdependent:

```
double min = 0.0;
double max = 0.0;
double sum = 0.0;
double avg = 0.0;

for(int i = 0; i <size; i++){
.
.
for(int j = 0; j < Withdrawals.length; j++){
   if(Withdrawals[User[i]] > max){  
      max = Withdrawals[j];  
   }  
   if(Withdrawals[User[i]] < min){  
      min = Withdrawals[j];  
   }
}  
sum += Withdrawals[j];
avg = sum/size;
}
```

how do i print the min, max, avg from the no of withdrawals per user ? :S

I have already counted the number of withdrawals per user.

Conditions are: create everything from scratch instead of using available library features of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide and conquer :) 
Yes, I know that is a term used for an algorithm technique, in this case what I mean is... work with small parts.

First having the min, max, avg for a simple array:

```
double[] values = {2,3,4,5,6,7};

double min = values[0];
double max = values[0];
double sum = 0;

for (double value : values) {
     min = Math.min(value, min);
     max = Math.max(value, max);
     sum += value;
}

double avg = sum / values.length;

System.out.println("Min: " + min);
System.out.println("Max: " + max);
System.out.println("Avg: " + avg);
```

**Note:** Since you can't use Java libraries for your assignment, is easy to do your own versions of the min/max functions (read the [Math JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html))

Now you can encapsulate this code in a function, you can start by returning another array:

```
static double[] minMaxAvg(double[] values) {
    double min = values[0];
    double max = values[0];
    double sum = 0;

    for (double value : values) {
        min = Math.min(value, min);
        max = Math.max(value, max);
        sum += value;
    }

    double avg = sum / values.length;

    return new double[] {min, max, avg};
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] values = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
    double[] info = minMaxAvg(values);
    System.out.println("Min: " + info[0]);
    System.out.println("Max: " + info[1]);
    System.out.println("Avg: " + info[2]);
}
```

Using an array is a little bit ugly to read, so is better if you create a class to hold the min, max, avg. So lets refactor the code a little bit:

```
class ValueSummary {
    final double min;
    final double max;
    final double avg;

    static ValueSummary createFor(double[] values) {
        double min = values[0];
        double max = values[0];
        double sum = 0;

        for (double value : values) {
            min = Math.min(value, min);
            max = Math.max(value, max);
            sum += value;
        }

        double avg = sum / values.length;

        return new ValueSummary(min, max, avg);
    }

    ValueSummary(double min, double max, double avg) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.avg = avg;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Min: " + min + "\nMax: " + max +"\nAvg: " + avg;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] values = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
    ValueSummary info = ValueSummary.createFor(values);
    System.out.println(info);
}
```

You don't specify it in your question, but I assume that you have an array for each user (maybe each withdrawals is another array).
Now that you have the bottom parts, we can switch to a [top-down thinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design).

So your code could be something like this:

```
for (User aUser : users) {
     System.out.println("User: " + aUser);
     System.out.println(ValueSummary.createFor(withdrawalsOf(aUser)));
}
```

Ok, but this is just the idea, you still have the problem to relate aUser with its withdrawals. You have several options here:

1. Make a "table" User-> Withdrawals, that is what you are trying to do with the two arrays. The User index in the array acts like a "user id". When you learn about Map you will see that you can use a better representation for the index.
2. Having a Map or array is just an optimization, of the relationship User->Withdrawls, but you can represent that relationship with an object (ie UserWithdrawls)

**Option 1:**

```
static class User {
    final String name;
    public User(String s) { name = s; }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User[] users = { new User("John"), new User("Doe")};
    double[][] withdrawals = {
         new double[] { 1, 2, 3}, new double[] { 10,22, 30} 
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("User: " + users[i].name);
        System.out.println(ValueSummary.createFor(withdrawals[i]));
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
static class User {
    final String name;
    public User(String s) { name = s; }
}
static class UserWithdrawls {
    final User user;
    final double[] withdrawals;
    final ValueSummary summary;
    UserWithdrawls(User user, double[] withdrawals) {
        this.user = user;
        this.withdrawals = withdrawals;
        this.summary = ValueSummary.createFor(withdrawals);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserWithdrawls[] userWithdrawls = {
            new UserWithdrawls(new User("John"), new double[] { 1, 2, 3}),
            new UserWithdrawls(new User("Doe"), new double[] { 10, 22, 30})
    };
    for (UserWithdrawls uw : userWithdrawls) {
        System.out.println("User: " + uw.user.name);
        System.out.println(uw.summary);
    }
}
```

**Additional notes:** If you are studying Computer Science, you'll learn in the future that the loop to calculate max, min, avg has a complexity of O(n). If the values array is fully loaded in memory, doing the max/min/avg in three different functions (thus reading the array 3 times) is still an algorithm of O(n) order with a bigger constant. With the power of today's computers the constant is so small, that most of the time you'll not get any gain from calculating min/max/avg in the same loop. In contrast you can gain code readability, for example in Groovy the minMaxAvg code could be written like this:

```
 def values = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
 println values.min()
 println values.max()
 println values.sum() / values.size()
```

Comment: all i can say is Thank you soo much for your time and effort put into explaining this, it helped me understand everything and hopefully helps others too..., thx Diego ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick n Dirty: Use a second for loop for the second array, but do not reinitialize the min, max etc again.

Cleaner would be to make a class to hold the min, max etc, and a method that is passed this result object and an array. The method then scans the array and updates the result objects min, max etc. Call the method for each array.

Comment: yea i wanted to use 2 methods minvalue and maxvalue, then call it but i am supposed to create these min max avg func from "scratch", what does that even mean as i am learning alice and this is java 1 or higher? lol O.o

Comment: java has built-in math functions - I think the teacher probably just means you have to write your own and not use existing methods.

Comment: this is what he said, so i can use math ?
"keep in mind, students are supposed to code everything from scratch instead of using available library features of Java, whenever possible."

Comment: None of my suggested solution aproaches requires you to use any of the prebuild classes, so whats your problem?

Comment: @Durandal, I want to create a second for loop but User is an Int and Withdrawals is a double, so i keep getting errors... :( could you please show me an example of how to in general look at 2 arrays when doing this, so i can figure out how things work....

Comment: maybe i am making it seem harder than it is ? :S

Comment: How would you determine which Withdrawal belongs to which User? Most likely your data model is screwed, each User needs to have its *own* Withdrawals. While its possible to store all Withdrawals in one array, you still need an auxilarity structure that tells you which Withdrawal belongs to which user. Think about that ... and maybe ask a *concise* question in the first place.

Comment: it doesn't matter which withdrawal belongs to which user as in similar ones or not, i have already counted the number of withdrawals per user, so basically
User 1 has made 3 withdrawals, User 2 has made 2, User 3 has made 1, User 4 has made 2 and User 5 has made 2. its clearly shown in the two arrays mentioned..., now i need to calculate the min max and avg based on the withdrawals per user...

Comment: So how do you then calculate the *correct* sum and average per User? I'm heading home, have a nice day :)

Comment: by looking at the number of withdrawls per user those withdrawals are for example: User 1 has withdrawals 90.00, 80.00, 70.00, based on this we need to calculate the min max avg..., i thought you were taking about similar withdrawals differentiating why does that matter since they are clearly show respectively which is made by whome in the array CLEARLY mentioned in my question... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to look at the code of [Descriptive Statistics](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html#a1.2_Descriptive_statistics) in the Commons Math library? Or better, use it instead of reinvent the wheel?

```
DescriptiveStatistics de = new DescriptiveStatistics();

de.addValue(..) // Your values
// Add more values

Double max = de.getMax();
Double min = de.getMin();
Double avg = de.getSum() / de.getN(); // or de.getMean();
```

And use an instance of DescriptiveStatistics for every array.

Comment: because this can be done with for loops and i want to know how... :S
besides this has to work for any array text file with x size...

Comment: LoL. That sounds more like an exam for ACM. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you stored the details for each user in a seperate data structure like the following class named `UserWithdrawals`.

```
public class Program1{
    public static class UserWithdrawals{
        private LinkedList<Double> withdrawals=new LinkedList<>();

        public void add(Double amt){
            this.withdrawals.add(amt);
        }

        public Double getMinimum(){
            Double min=this.withdrawals.get(0);
            for(Double amt:this.withdrawals)
                if(amt.compareTo(min)<0) min=amt;
            return min;
        }

        public Double getMaximum(){
            Double max=this.withdrawals.get(0);
            for(Double amt:this.withdrawals)
                if(amt.compareTo(max)>0) max=amt;
            return max;
        }


        public Double getAverage(){
            Double sum=new Double(0);
            for(Double amt:this.withdrawals)
                sum+=amt;
            return sum/this.withdrawals.size();
            //this method will fail if the withdrawals list is updated during the iteration
        }

        /*You can also combine the three into a single method and return an array of Double object coz the iteration is same.*/

    }

    /*now you iterate over your two array lists (This wont work if the two array lists - 'Users' and 'Withdrawals' are of different size) and store the withdrawal data associated with a user in the corresponding map value - Maps or Associative arrays are a very basic data structure so your professor should not have any problems with this*/

    private HashMap<Integer,UserWithdrawals> withdrawals_map=new HashMap<>();

    public Program1(ArrayList<Integer> Users, ArrayList<Double> Withdrawals){
        for(int i=0;i<Users.size();i++){
            Integer user_no=Users.get(i);
            Double withdrawal_amt=Withdrawals.get(i);
            if(this.withdrawals_map.get(user_no)==null){
                this.withdrawals_map.put(user_no,new UserWithdrawals());
            }
            this.withdrawals_map.get(user_no).add(withdrawal_amt);
        }
    }

    public UserWithdrawals getUserWithdrawalsData(Integer user_no){
        return this.withdrawals_map.get(user_no);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are also many many different ways to accomplish the same, depending on the optimization required

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the 2D array in O(log(n)) based on 1st column, by using c++ STL Sort function.
2. Traverse in O(n) to calculate the average and update MaxAverage.

   ```
   // Driver function to sort the 2D vector
   // on basis of a particular column

   bool sortcol( const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2 ) {
       return v1[0] < v2[0];
   }

   void sortMatrix()
   {
   // Initializing 2D vector "vect" with
   // values S_ID,MARKS
   vector< vector<int> > vect{{1,85}, {2,90}, {1,87}, {1,99}, {3,70}};

   // Number of rows
   int m = vect.size();

   // Number of columns
   int n = vect[0].size();

   // Use of "sort()" for sorting on basis
   // of 1st column
   sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(),sortcol);

   float maxAverage=-1;
   int id=1; // assuming it starts from 1.
   float sum=0;
   int s=0; // size of marks per student to calculate average
   for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )
   {
       sum+=vect[i][1];
       s=s+1;
       if( i+1!= m && vect[i+1][0] != vect[i][0] ){// gotten all the marks of this student
           maxAverage = maxAverage>sum/s? maxAverage:sum/s;
           id = vect[i][0];
           s=0;
           sum=0;
       }
   }
   cout<<"ID: "<<id<<"\tValue: "<<maxAverage<<endl;
   }
   ```

Output:

```
ID: 2   Value: 90.3333
```